# Taylor expansion of a charge density (multipole radiation)

Tags: electromagnetism, multipole-expansion

I'm a little confused about this expansion (maybe because its to late). Could someone write the taylor series down in a more general way (as a sum for example)? It would help me to understand where every term came from. I would really appreciate it! Thank you for all your help!
[image]

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: What's wrong with using the definition of taylor series off say wikipedia or wolfram's site?